# Apache rewrite proxy all content and pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want apache .htaccess configuration for rewrite all pages and content form domain1 to domain2. And includes port, example :8050

On domain2, i have configuration

```
 <IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.html
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain1.tld/$1 [P,L]
   </IFModule>
```

But I have problem with this code. This rewrite only static data (html, images...) from index page.

I want to rewrite shoutcast stream, for example domain1.tld:8050 to domain2.tld:8050. How I can make this?

Comment: Why can't you simply add a second rule for that second port for streaming? It is another base URL after all.

Comment: I can't modify any content on domain1 because this is hosting provider link. I wont to hide provider and use domain2.

Comment: Ah, so you want to steal content and pretend it is your own content. I see. ;-)

Comment: Yes. I want to rewrite complete domain includes ports. Why? Because I can easy change hosting provider and I will always have the same URL :)

Comment: You are aware that this comes with the penalty of a network latency? Not a good idea for streaming things... Anyway, as said initially: create two separate rules, one for the web pages, one for the streamed media content.

Comment: How I can create two separate rules?

Comment: By using the `RewriteRule` command twice with different parameters...

Comment: Use `ProxyPass` instead.